# Как выбрать по условию элементы коллекции и изменить их значения?

Tags: c#

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста по такому вопросу, имеется коллекция значений типа Sensors

```
public class Sensor
{
   public SensorType SensorType { get; set; }
   public int RegisterAddress { get; set; }
   public int BitNumber { get; set; }
   public int Position { get; set; }
   public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Как для элементов с заданным SensorType изменить Value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (var sensor in sensors.Where(s => s.SensorType == selectedType))
  sensor.Value = newValue;
```

Если коллекция из структур (int к примеру), то лучше делать как то так:

```
  var list = new List<int>();
  for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
  {
    if (someCondition)
      list[i] = newValue;
  }
```

Comment: Работает, а не могли бы объяснить, почему в такой же ситуации, если sensors будет List<int>, то при попытке присвоить значение sensor компилятор выдает ошибку readonly local variable?

Comment: @AntonPopov дополнил ответ

Comment: Ясно, спасибо...

Answer (score 0):

```
sensors=sensors.Select(x=>
{
    x.Value=x.SensorType==selectedType?newValue:x.value;
    return x;
});
```

Comment: Ух ты, вы серьезно так пишете код, что всего один пробел на эту конструкцию?

Comment: Пробелы обычно студия выставляет по закрытию фигурных скобок :)